# Scala - Generic implicit with lower bound

Tags: scala, generics, implicit-conversion, implicit

Consider the following:

```scala
class Super
class Sub extends Super

implicit val implicitOption: Option[Super] = None
def f[A, B >: A](a: A)(implicit i: Option[B]) = println("It worked")
```

If I call `f(new Super)`, it works fine, but `f(new Sub)` gives me a compilation error (could not find implicit value for parameter `i`).

Why can't `implicitOption` be used as the implicit parameter when `A = Sub`?

Comment: The compiler hasn't any input to infer `B`. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you're getting at but could you elaborate?

Comment: Depending on what you really want to do / really need to solve. We may come with a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I see what you mean. I started off with a simpler problem and overcomplicated things with the `B` parameter. Solved it a different way now, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be to move the parameter `B` from `f` to `implicitOption` by changing their definitions like this.

```scala
implicit def implicitOption[B <: Super]: Option[B] = None
def f[A](a: A)(implicit i: Option[A]) = println("It worked")
```

Comment: This is very different from the question. Now `implicitOption` is divorced from and unrelated to `Super` and `Sub`, and the type parameters to `implicitOption` and `f()` are now completely independent, unrelated, and unbounded.

Comment: Fair point. I've edited the type parameter to `implicitOption` to connect it to `Super`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, compiler needs some help figuring out which `B` to use. So

```
f[Sub, Super](new Sub)
```

works just fine.

### --- Old answer - still relevant but approaches from different perspective --

Because `Option` is covariant - which means you can pass `Option[Sub]` where `Option[Super]` is expected, but not the vice versa.

To make this work, you'd need a contravariant class (let's call it `ContraOption` for now) - so that you can pass `ContraOption[Super]` where `ContraOption[Sub]` is expected.

Continuing on your example:

```
class Super
class Sub extends Super

implicit val implicitOption: Option[Super] = None

sealed abstract class ContraOption[-A]
case object ContraNone extends ContraOption[Any]
case class ContraSome[A](value: A) extends ContraOption[A]

implicit val implicitContraOption: ContraOption[Super] = ContraNone

def f[A, B >: A](a: A)(implicit i: Option[B]) = println("It worked")
def f2[A, B >: A](a: A)(implicit i: ContraOption[B]) = println("It worked 2")

f(new Super)  // It worked
f2(new Sub)   // It worked 2
```

Note that both trying to do `f(new Sub)` (as in your example) and `f2(new Super)` fails compilation with "implicit not found".

For more fundamental understanding of co- and contravariance, please refer to the [docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html). But simply put, covariant generic class "follows" the ancestor-descendent links, while contravariant classes reverse the direction. To illustrate (in pseudo-scala):

```
class Super
class Sub extends Super

class Covariant[+A]
class Contravariant[-A]

This gives us the following relationships:
Sub <: Super
Covariant[Sub] <: Covariant[Super]
Contravariant[Super] <: Covariant[Sub]
```

Comment: In my example, `Option[B]` is expected where `B >: A`. So wouldn't `None: Option[Super]` be accepted when `A` is `Sub`?

Comment: You're right, updated (more like "rewritten, but kept the old one for future reference" :))